# FxPlug communicate between mainThread and CustomWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to sent image data back from custom window I created.
I tried delegate but it seem not to work, idk if because they on a different thread that why the implement is not work.

Here is delegate file

```
@protocol ViewShotDelegate<NSObject>
- (void) SentHelp:(NSString *) data;
@end
```

Plugin Class MainPlugin

```
@implementation MainPlugin
- (void) SentHelp:(NSString *) data{
      NSLog(data);

}
```

other class CustomWindow accessor

```
@interface CustomWindow: NSWindowController <ViewShotDelegate>
   @property(nonatomic,weak)  id<ViewShotDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation CustomWindow
- (IBAction)SentHelp:(id)sender{
      NSLog(@"Help!!!");
}
```

I got suggest another suggest is using sharecontext like CGLContextObj, But I not really get it how to use the share context to draw. And the example and document just too vague, Can some one give me a barebone version of how to use sharecontext, just a simple create window, have button, click button and a triangle appear in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

So In the end. I use NSImage to store the screen shot of the view.

```
// this in interface
   NSImage* image;
   @property (assign) IBOutlet NSView *someView; 
//This in body some where, called when you want to take screen shot.
   image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[someView 
dataWithPDFInsideRect:[someView bounds]]];
```

After that in renderOutput, you can keep checking if window capture a screen shot. then call a function to get back the image.

```
// this in the renderOutput
 if (wc.isUpdate){
 NSImage* newimage = [wc GetImage];
 }
```

Once you got image, just go ahead to create texture ( convert to NSBitmapImageRep and call glTexImage2D

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             0,
             samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, 
             (int)[bMaps pixelsWide], 
             (int)[bMaps pixelsHigh], 
             0, 
             samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, 
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [bMaps bitmapData]);
```

Then apply to a squad that you want.